# Build Bundle(s): Errors while building Bundle file-->File 'root/res/drawable/sr_list_item_background.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'

Tags: javascript, java, android, gradle, bundle

[file tree image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxoPF.png)I am getting this error while build bundle file.But .Apk file build successfully.
Facing this kind of problem new
following error message

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebugBundle'.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$FileUsesReservedNameException: File 'root/res/drawable/sr_list_item_background.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.
>       at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
>       at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:788)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:755)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
>       ... 33 more
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$FileUsesReservedNameException: File 'root/res/drawable/sr_list_item_background.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
>       at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.close(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:56)
>       at kotlin.io.CloseableKt.closeFinally(Closeable.kt:65)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.BundleTask.bundleModules(BundleTask.kt:128)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>       ... 45 more
>   Caused by: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$FileUsesReservedNameException: File 'root/res/drawable/sr_list_item_background.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.
>       at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.validation.BundleFilesValidator.validateModuleFile(BundleFilesValidator.java:112)
>       at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.validation.ValidatorRunner.validateBundleModulesUsingSubValidator(ValidatorRunner.java:81)
>       at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.validation.ValidatorRunner.lambda$validateBundleModules$4(ValidatorRunner.java:64)
>       at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:406)
>       at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.validation.ValidatorRunner.validateBundleModules(ValidatorRunner.java:63)
>       at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.validation.BundleModulesValidator.validate(BundleModulesValidator.java:101)
>       at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.BuildBundleCommand.validateInput(BuildBundleCommand.java:244)
>       at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.BuildBundleCommand.execute(BuildBundleCommand.java:162)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.BundleTask$BundleToolRunnable.run(BundleTask.kt:201)
>       at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:39)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalInterruptibleAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:361)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1001)
>       ... 53 more

```
manifest.xml is below
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- AdxmiSdk Permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
    
    <permission
        android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

         <!-- Below is optional -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.app.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.AppActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppLTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.SignupActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".IntroActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:label="Intro Activity">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppLTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.EarningHistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.RedeemHistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
   
        <activity android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.RecoveryActivity" >
        </activity>
      
        <activity
            android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.RedeemActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.InstructionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.ReferActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.ErrorActivity"
            android:label="Internet disConnected" >
        </activity>

        <!-- This activity is the activity that will be launched by the alarm -->


        <!-- Necessary components that SuperSonic / Ironsource needs-->

        <activity
            android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.ControllerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.InterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.OpenUrlActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    
   <activity
         android:name="com.playerize.superrewards.activities.SRWebViewActivity" 
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     />


       <!-- Necessary components that AdxmiSDK needs -->
        <activity
            android:name="net.adxmi.android.AdBrowser"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="net.adxmi.android.AdService"
            android:exported="false" >
        </service>

           <!-- Optional components that AdxmiSDK needs -->
        <receiver android:name="net.adxmi.android.AdReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />

                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

         <!-- Component that rewarded ADs needs -->
        <service
            android:name="net.adxmi.android.ExpService"
            android:exported="false" >
        </service>

        <!--  WhiteMobi Components -->

        <activity android:name="com.white.mobi.sdk.WMOfferWall"/>

        <!-- Component that firebase needs -->

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <!--Component that paly video ADs needs-->
    <activity
    android:name="net.adxmi.android.video.VideoActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>

        <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <!-- the libraries that google play service configuration need to use -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- Nativex Comnponents-->
        <activity
            android:name="com.nativex.monetization.activities.InterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            />
        <activity
            android:name="com.nativex.videoplayer.VideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />

        <!-- END Nativex Comnponents  -->

        <!-- Facebook components -->

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- END Facebook components -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle** project

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle app**

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xx.xx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 20
        versionName "2.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

// Maven Repositories
repositories {

    google()
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/ironsource-mobile/android-sdk" }
    maven { url "https://bitbucket.org/adscend/androidsdk/raw/master/" }
    maven { name "Fyber's maven repo"
            url "https://fyber.bintray.com/maven" }

}

dependencies {

    // test Libraries
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Android Support Libraries
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'

    // Adnetwork Libraries
    implementation 'com.fyber:fyber-sdk:8.19.0'
    implementation(name: 'adgatemediasdk', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'OfferToroSdk-v3.1.10', ext: 'aar')
    implementation 'com.adscendmedia.sdk:adscendmedia:2.3.4'
    implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:6.7.4@jar'

    // MultiDex Dependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    // Other Libraries
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    implementation 'com.facebook.network.connectionclass:connectionclass:1.0.1'

    // Facebook Login only
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.36.0'

    // slider library
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'

    // Google Libraries
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of the file structure and where the file `sr_list_item_background.xml` is...

Comment: Hi, did you create an extra res folder for that xml file ?

Comment: I did'nt create it@SreedevPR

Comment: Finally found it    [https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxoPF.png] its inside libs .jar file can't edit@SubrataMondal

Comment: hi. how did you resolved these issue?

Comment: @chandankumar did your issue got resolved?

Comment: @KaranKhurana not yet.

Comment: @chandankumar check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57688634/4776577, It should solve your issue ?

Comment: still facing the same issue while creating bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved similar error of mine by adding packagingOptions in **build.gradle.**

You also try adding following line in your build.gradle :

```
android {
 ...

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'res/drawable/sr_list_item_background.xml'
    }
}
```

I think this should solve the issue.

**Reason :** I am not sure but I'm guessing it would remove this particular file while building bundle.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution but similar error comes with the different file name. i exclude them too. it's coming again and again for different different files. how to get rid of it?

Comment: As its too long can't paste here.

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$FileUsesReservedNameException: File 'root/res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$FileUsesReservedNameException: File 'root/res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.

Comment: and this log is showing up when i exclude these below files.::   

exclude 'res/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_launcher_background.xml'
exclude 'res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
exclude 'res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_background.png'
exclude 'res/drawable-v24/ic_launcher_foreground.xml'
exclude 'res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
exclude 'res/layout/activity_main.xml'
exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
exclude 'res/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round.png'

Comment: Try this ---- exclude 'res/mipmap'

Comment: In my case, the error was like "File 'root/res/values/strings.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'." & I resolved it by adding  packagingOptions {
        exclude 'res/values/strings.xml'
    }. in gradle file android{} section